Keep websocket alive
I have a websocket subscription watcher:
async def run():
    start = get_start_status() ### ON/OFF
    
    while start == 1:
        
        live = True
                
        while live == True:
            
            try:
                async with websockets.connect(WEBSOCKET_URL, timeout=15, ping_interval=10) as websocket:

                    # Send subscription request
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps({
                        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                        "id": 1,
                        "method": ###...
                        "params": ###...
                    }))


                    first_resp = await websocket.recv()
                    response_dict = json.loads(first_resp)
                    if 'result' in response_dict:
                        print("Subscription successful. Subscription ID: ", response_dict['result'])
                        
                    
                    # Continuously read from the WebSocket
                    async for response in websocket:

                        response_dict = json.loads(response)

                        ### TO DO WiTH RESPONSES

            except ConnectionTimeoutError as e:
                print('Error connecting. Retrying...')
                live = False
                
async def main():
    
    asyncio.ensure_future(run())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
        
asyncio.run(main())

It works properly, but at some point it freezes and stops accepting responses. The  timeout=15, ping_interval=10 don't help, it just hangs indefinitely until a manual reboot.
I understand that I need to insert a ping-pong function that will periodically check its performance. But I don't understand where and how to add a checker. How can I keep my websocket alive?

This behavior is not normal, who is closing the connection? The client or the server? Maybe your server doesn't support keepalive messages and acts weird, you can try to disable it with ping_interval=None. Btw., you can use async for instead of async with to take advantage of reconnect handling by websockets module.

Thank you! 'async for' and 'ping_interval=None' is the solution for my case.

Hmmm.. Websocket was alive more time, but it freeze anyway... More ideas?

No, I believe you need to find the cause of the problem by experimentation, find out where the freeze is actually happening. Maybe it is the first recv() call and the server is not reliably sending a message upon (re-)connecting?

Yes I do. Thank you, 'async for' made my websocket alive longer.
